# Getting symmetric matrix coordinates based off of condition in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, boolean-logic

I have a symmetric matrix, or a dataframe, whatever is easier, in R.  `df`.

I want to get all the `(row name, column name)` pairs for which the element in the matrix is >= 0.90.
However, I would like to exclude diagonal elements.  Also, I would like the elements to be unique in the sense that (x,y) is the same as (y,x)

For example:

```
df
   A      B     C       D    E
A   1    0.4    0.4    0.1  0.9
B  0.4   1      0.4    0.4  0.1
C  0.4   0.4    1      0.1  0.3
D  0.1   0.4    0.1     1   0.1
E  0.9   0.1    0.3    0.1   1
```

I would want just

(E,A) or (A,E)  (only one of them is needed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have a test matrix like

```
mm <- structure(c(1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1, 0.9, 0.4, 1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 
0.4, 1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 
1), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
"E"), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")))
```

You can get the indexes of the row/cols that match your criteria with

```
idx <- which(mm>=.9 & lower.tri(mm), arr.ind=TRUE)
```

and then you can get the names with

```
cbind(rownames(mm)[idx[,1]], colnames(mm)[idx[,2]])

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "E"  "A"
```